# How can I remove the [INFO] and [ERROR] tags from Maven output?

Tags: java, maven

I have a failing Maven build, and I want to copy and paste the output into a ticket. However, every single line of output includes a tag such as `[INFO]` or `[ERROR]` on front of it. How can I tell Maven to run a build and not include these tags, so that I can get a clean copy of the output?

I'm using Maven 3.6.2.

Comment: I've posted a self-answer, but I'd really prefer a mechanism to disable the output rather than edit it out.

Comment: What makes removing the tag "cleaner"?

Comment: @JimGarrison I am needing to copy and paste the compiler output into a ticket, and having the tag at the front of every line means that (1) whitespace can't get automatically stripped and (2) syntax detection won't work (in addition to wasting horizontal space for what tend to be long lines anyway).

Comment: Maybe [this](https://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html) helps

Answer (score 1):

You can *filter* the output using `cut`:

```
$ mvn test | cut -d' ' -f2-
```